# UIViewController class

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

If I am using multiple viewControllers, do I need to create a separate UIViewContoller class for each one of them or can I associate this same new class with each individual viewController? Under what circumstances would I create a new class to associate with a  separate VC?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View controllers manage the logic of your view, providing a way to channel the data between the view and the mode, and react to events initiated by end-users through the user interface.

If multiple views happen to share the same logic of model-view interaction, it is a good idea to share view controllers among them. However, this is somewhat rare: in practice, different views call for different view controllers. So in practice you create a new class for a new view controller almost every time that you need a view controller. You can also start with several view controllers, and then unify some of them if you spot sufficient number of commonality in their code.

Comment: @user1542067 You are welcome! If this answers your questions, consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This will indicate to others that you are not actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.